# How do I correctly set up NServiceBus to use remote error queue?

Tags: nservicebus

I am trying to set up NServiceBus to use a remote error queue to ease the management of checking for errors.  When I do this, I get the following error when NServiceBus.Host.exe starts up:

> 2010-03-25 07:59:50,103 [1] ERROR NServiceBus.Utils.MsmqUtilities [(null)] <(null)> - Could not create queue error@C0NSERVICEBUS or check its existence. Processing will still continue.
>   System.Messaging.MessageQueueException: Invalid queue path name.
>      at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.ResolveFormatNameFromQueuePath(String queuePath, Boolean throwException)
>      at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.Exists(String path)
>      at NServiceBus.Utils.MsmqUtilities.CreateQueueIfNecessary(String queueName)

Here are my config settings for NServiceBus:

```
    <!-- in order to configure remote endpoints use the format: "queue@machine" 
   input queue must be on the same machine as the process feeding off of it.
   error queue can (and often should) be on a different machine.  -->

<MsmqTransportConfig InputQueue="ClipboardSubscriberInputQueue" ErrorQueue="error@C0NSERVICEBUS" NumberOfWorkerThreads="1" MaxRetries="5"/>

<UnicastBusConfig>
    <MessageEndpointMappings>
        <add Messages="PatientFirst.Messaging" Endpoint="ClipboardPublisherInputQueue@C0NSERVICEBUS"/>
    </MessageEndpointMappings>
</UnicastBusConfig>
```

Is this normal expected behavior, if not what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is normal behavior.

NServiceBus tries to automatically create queues for you when it can. When it can't, it's lower level components may complain, but as you saw in the logs, the higher level components continue working.